# bubble chart color by parent class

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am looking at the Bubble Chart by Mike Bostock: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530 that uses circle packing. I would like to however, be able to color the circles by the name of the containing class.

[image]

I am trying it in JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/qoveguvopu/edit?css,js,output

My fault is here:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.data.name);});
```

Thanks!

Kind of like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data bound to the parent...

```
d.parent.data.name
```

... and color the circles according to it, first checking if a parent exists:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.parent) {
            return color(d.parent.data.name)
        };
    });
```

Here is your updated Bin: http://jsbin.com/ruyegidopo/1/edit

Comment: this is good but it still looks colored by Name...or am I missing something. I was hoping for the children to be all the same color, but only ones that are on their own leaf. So if there is that "blue" circle that encompasses smaller ones, but none of the small ones inside of it have their own children, then they are all the same color. Please see the image above.

Comment: That's it. I really need to learn some JS...Thanks for the great answer!